# Which indefinite progress spinner is better?

Tags: website-design, loading, comparison

I have two styles of "indefinite progress" spinner to choose from:

They are both variations of the typical [image: spinner], but The First spins the entire image, while The Second rotates which shade of grey corresponds to which "petal". Which is better from a UX standpoint?

http://jsfiddle.net/5Tg7k/ for those with animation-supporting browsers, or:

`<svg height="20" width="40">
    <g> <!-- Option the First -->
        <line x1="10" y1="3" x2="10" y2="7" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" />
        <line x1="10" y1="3" x2="10" y2="7" stroke="rgb(32, 32, 32)" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="rotate(-45 10 10)"/>
        <line x1="10" y1="3" x2="10" y2="7" stroke="rgb(64, 64, 64)" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="rotate(-90 10 10)"/>
        <line x1="10" y1="3" x2="10" y2="7" stroke="rgb(96, 96, 96)" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="rotate(-135 10 10)"/>
        <line x1="10" y1="3" x2="10" y2="7" stroke="rgb(128, 128, 128)" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="rotate(-180 10 10)"/>
        <line x1="10" y1="3" x2="10" y2="7" stroke="rgb(160, 160, 160)" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="rotate(-225 10 10)"/>
        <line x1="10" y1="3" x2="10" y2="7" stroke="rgb(192, 192, 192)" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="rotate(-270 10 10)"/>
        <line x1="10" y1="3" x2="10" y2="7" stroke="rgb(224, 224, 224)" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="rotate(-315 10 10)"/>
        <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 10 10" to="360 10 10" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </g>
    <g> <!-- Option the Second -->
        <line x1="30" y1="3" x2="30" y2="7" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" >
            <animate attributeType="xml" attributeName="stroke" from="#000000" to="#ffffff" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        </line>
        <line x1="30" y1="3" x2="30" y2="7" stroke="rgb(32, 32, 32)" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="rotate(-45 30 10)">
            <animate attributeType="xml" attributeName="stroke" from="#000000" to="#ffffff" begin="0.875s" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        </line>
        <line x1="30" y1="3" x2="30" y2="7" stroke="rgb(64, 64, 64)" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="rotate(-90 30 10)">
            <animate attributeType="xml" attributeName="stroke" from="#000000" to="#ffffff" begin="0.75s" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        </line>
        <line x1="30" y1="3" x2="30" y2="7" stroke="rgb(96, 96, 96)" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="rotate(-135 30 10)">
            <animate attributeType="xml" attributeName="stroke" from="#000000" to="#ffffff" begin="0.625s" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        </line>
        <line x1="30" y1="3" x2="30" y2="7" stroke="rgb(128, 128, 128)" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="rotate(-180 30 10)">
            <animate attributeType="xml" attributeName="stroke" from="#000000" to="#ffffff" begin="0.5s" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        </line>
        <line x1="30" y1="3" x2="30" y2="7" stroke="rgb(160, 160, 160)" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="rotate(-225 30 10)">
            <animate attributeType="xml" attributeName="stroke" from="#000000" to="#ffffff" begin="0.375s" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        </line>
        <line x1="30" y1="3" x2="30" y2="7" stroke="rgb(192, 192, 192)" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="rotate(-270 30 10)">
            <animate attributeType="xml" attributeName="stroke" from="#000000" to="#ffffff" begin="0.25s" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        </line>
        <line x1="30" y1="3" x2="30" y2="7" stroke="rgb(224, 224, 224)" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="rotate(-315 30 10)">
            <animate attributeType="xml" attributeName="stroke" from="#000000" to="#ffffff" begin="0.125s" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        </line>
    </g>
</svg>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one is much lighter on the eye, and much more fluid. The last thing you want is your users being distracted or irritated by the high-speed loading animation.

... though this is a very, very subjective question!

**UPDATE**
Sorry, not really high-speed, just greater movement

Comment: They are the same speed (1 rev/sec), but the top did look much faster to my eye, too.

Comment: sorry, more like greater movement but it is harsher on the eye :)

Comment: +1 The first one looks more like a cog spinning. The second one looks more like the rotating of highlighted LEDs.